# Wrap text for container of undefined width

Tags: css, word-wrap

In [my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/n4c24cg7/2/), I would like to split the text into 2 lines. The splitting needs to be like in the image below:

### [image]

The splitting needs to be according to the width of the image.

I tried playing with `word-break` but it seems that it needs width of the container to be defined.

Is there a way to fix this using CSS only?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/n4c24cg7/2/)

Comment: You have to fix width in px or in %.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `display: table-caption` property to make an item fit the width its container already had without stretching it, and reset the `white-space` to make sure the lines actually break when it gets too wide:

```
span.item a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-caption;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Then add a `vertical-align: top` to your `span.item` to make them line up nicely.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n4c24cg7/4/

Answer inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26004447/124238).

Comment: Is there a way I can wrap it in 2 lines only and the overflowing text can be denoted by `...` ?

Comment: Not with just CSS. `text-overflow:ellipsis` works only for one line

Comment: `display: table-caption`? Dear god, where has this been all my life.

Answer (score 0):

) this should do the trick:

```
div.items div{
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.container {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.item {
    width: 1%;
    display: inline-table;
    padding:0px 15px;
}
a {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration:none;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n4c24cg7/6/

the padding is only cosmetic, by the way, can be adjusted at will. it might also be worth looking into the 'ellipsis'property to stick to the layout: Setting a fixed HEIGHT on the boxes will chop off the text in this scenario... Depending on what browsers you are counting on and the size of the text/caption coming after the images -- right now they align with the highest ;) hope this helps

Comment: as an after note... the real breaker on being able to scroll this horizontally is to keep the whitespace-nowrap contained in the outer elements, while letting your text break whenever it should

Answer (score -3):

You can find solution from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_gallery.asp)

```
  <div class="img">
     <img src="image/path/img" alt="">
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here blah blah blah</div>
    </div>
```

css

```
   div
   {
     width:100%;/*or specify width*/   
   }
   div.img {
    width:100%;
    }
    div.desc {
      margin: 5px;
      padding:5px;
      word-wrap:break-word;
    }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uL0oq26v/)